# \nocite and pagebackref option

Tags: bibliographies, citing, back-referencing

I'm interested in using `\nocite` and `pagebackref` together which sounds a bit strange.
I'd like to get bibliographic references at the end of a document with mention of the page where they appear (hence the use of `pagebackref`) but with no specific reference in the text (like the usual [1] number, hence the use of `\nocite`). Maybe, I could use `\cite` instead but using an option with no reference? References in the page will be achieved through footnotes. `endnote` and `footbib` packages do not seem to offer solutions of this type but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\let\oldnocite\nocite
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\nocite}[1]{\oldnocite{#1}\Hy@backout{#1}}
\makeatother
```